# EF 6.1.3, Linq query with the filter where columnname == NULL is not fetching any rows

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

Technology: EF 6.1.3, Database First Approach and SQL Server.

Issue: I'm facing an issue with the following Linq Query,

```
EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();
IQueryable<Model.Employee> employees = from e in db.Employee
                                       where e.EmployeeName == null
                                       select e;
```

I'm trying to get employees whose EmployeeName is Null but I'm not getting any records, whereas when I query in the database (SQL Server), I'm getting the results properly.

I suspect the linq query is not converting where clause as `EmployeeName IS NULL` but it simply converts like `EmployeeName == null`.

Please let me know how to fix this issue..

Thanks,
Prakash.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL, e.g. `var sql = employees.ToString();`

Comment: Maybe EmployeeName is not null but the empty string. Can you check what happens if you add `|| e.EmployeeName.Equals("")` to your `where` clause?

Comment: In EF 6 you can use where string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.EmployeeName)

Comment: @LiviuM. Ok cool, I did not know that. I remember it being broken in Linq queries, not sure about the EF version though.

Comment: WHERE ([Extent1].[EmployeeName] = @p__linq__0)

Due to office reason I didn't paste full code..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ToList()` to materialize the query. EF will definitely convert to the proper operator in SQL.

So the code becomes:

```
List<Model.Employee> employees = (from e in db.Employee
                                       where e.EmployeeName == null
                                       select e).ToList();
```

Comment: yes.. I'm using ToList() to get the result but it is not returning any rows which has null in EmployeeName column..